# Visual Studio does not see all merge differences. How can I add them?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022, git-merge

So far, I only used the Visual Studio 2022 GUI.
On master, I committed some changes in file A. Then I realized, I should have created a new branch for those changes. So, I created a new branch feature-x and reverted the changes on master. I kept the changes on feature-x. On master and feature-x, I committed more changes. Today, I wanted to merge feature-x into master. There are certain changes on feature-x in file A that were on master, but were reverted. The merge process does not see these as changes. So, although there is a change in file A on feature-x, the merge does not show file A and the changes as "Staged Changes" or as "Unmerged Changes". This even results in erroneous code, because in file B a variable from file A is used but this variable is now not declared.
How can I add the changes to the merge?

Here's an image for clarification:

[image: git history]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "reverted the changes on master"? Do you mean you reset master to a commit in the history of feature-x, or did you run `git revert` to create a commit that reverted the modifications to file A? (or something else?)

Comment: Right click on the commit > "Revert"

Comment: If on `master` you did a _**revert**_ of the commit that you kept in `feature-x` (instead of repointing the branch to the commit it should have stayed on, the one before **the commit**), then it is to be expected that if you try to _merge_ them, the changes from **the commit** will be gone in the resulting merge.

Comment: Why? Does not make sense to me. I first reverted it, then I committed the changes on feature-x. So, the changes on feature-x were conducted after the revert and so, they are newer.

Comment: It sounds like that's your problem. `git revert` creates a new commit that "logically undoes" a commit. It doesn't actually remove the commit from the branch's history. The original changes to file A are in the histories of both feature-x and master. From git's perspective, these changes are ancient history. The only changes that are being considered for the purposes of the merge are the new changes made in the master branch (the ones from the `revert` commit). Since these don't conflict with anything in feature-x, that's the contents that you end up with in file-A.

Comment: See also [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/927358/11082165), [What's the difference between Git Revert, Checkout and Reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8358035/11082165)

Comment: I am not sure, if I understand you correctly, but I think, you misunderstand me. Let me clarify: On master, I committed "start with feature x". Then, I created the branch feature-x on base of the commit "start with feature x". On master, I reverted "start with feature x", on feature-x, I kept it.

Comment: @Flippowitsch Right, that's what I understood from your description. The problem is that "reverting" a commit has particular meaning in git, and that meaning isn't quite what you wanted it to do. When you "reverted" the commit "start with feature x" in master, what you actually did is create a *new commit* with the old state of file A. The commit "start with feature x" is still in the history of master. Since both branches contain that commit in their histories, it's irrelevant as far as the merge is concerned.

Comment: Yeah... _that_ is the problem. Consider what git _sees_ when merging both branches..... so... what is the last commit that is present in both branches? The commit you made on  `master`  but intended to keep it in the other branch, right? Ok.... so, what is going to be considered for the merge coming from `master`  after that commit??? I will give you a tip: **Not what you have in mind**. Do a diff between `master`  and that commit and see for yourself.

Comment: As far as steps forward, the "cleanest" thing to do would be to remove both "start with feature x" and "Revert start with feature x" from the history of master, then merge as normal. If you're comfortable with git's CLI, the easiest way to do that is with an interactive rebase. You should be able to find questions on this site and elsewhere online on how rewrite histories to remove old commits. One is [Remove old git commits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9725156/11082165)

Comment: Maybe, I got it. I added an image to the question. You mean, when I merge feature-x into master, there is no difference in file A between the last commit on feature-x and the commit "add ex...". I thought, the merge process compares the last commits for both, master and feature-x.

Comment: Nope.... that's not how it works.... it merges _differences_ since their last common ancestor (it's actually more complex than this but this is a valid simplification) ..... merging by just looking at just the tips would make merging impossible, actually. You _really_ don't know what has been added/deleted/modified by just looking at the tips.

Comment: @Flippowitsch Not quite. Take a look at the histories of feature-x and master. They both include the commit "start with feature x". That change is done. There's no difference between that change and every older change in the entire history of the repo. When you got about merging feature-x and master, only commits that come _after_ their common ancestor matter. At merge time, what git sees is that there are **zero changes** made to file A in feature-x and some changes make to file A in master (the changes in the "revert" commit). Those histories can be safely merged by using the master contents

Comment: Did you ever push your local copy of `master` yet with the reverts? If no, you should `reset` your local `master` instead of `revert`. If yes, on your feature branch, you can either revert the revert, or rewrite the commit(s) so they have different commit IDs, and then you can merge them in again. (It's the commit IDs that matter, not the time you create the commits. Though, if you change the time, the commit IDs will change also.)

Comment: @Flippowitsch Be sure to read carefully what was said about `git revert` above and in the provided links. The problem here has to do with a difference between what you wanted git to do and what git was actually told. Creating the revert commit didn't undo the original commit, it just made some more changes to file A, exactly as if you had edited it manually.

Comment: @TTT Just to be clear, `reset` is what the OP would have wanted to do back when the feature branch was created. Unfortunately, there's now a week's worth of new commits on their master branch, so a simple reset will no longer do the trick. They'll need to do some rebasing/cherry-picking if they want to separate the old "start with feature x" from master's history.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Yeah, good point, I wasn't entirely clear about what to do with those commits that came after. I was basing this on "On master and feature-x, I committed more changes." So if OP hasn't pushed `master`, then it can be completely rewritten if desired. If it were me and it wasn't pushed yet, I'd just reset it back and then remerge or rebase any needed commits after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a rather simple solution: I cherry-picked the commits starting with the commit, I reverted on master. In above image, there are no commit IDs, so below, there are the corresponding times.
`git cherry-pick --no-edit <id of commit from 15:19:02> <id of commit from 8:11:43> <id of commit from 10:44:53> <id of commit from 11:48:44>`
`--no-edit` tells git to keep the commit message.
There were merge conflicts with 2 commits. I solved them and continued with `git cherry-pick --continue`.

Comment: Valid approach. To save having to manually copy all those commit ids, you can pass a commit range to `git cherry-pick` (see the description of the [`<commit>...`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt-ltcommitgt82308203) option in the documentation). Or even simpler, you could use `git rebase -i <id of the revert commit>~1` to be presented with a list of commit IDs in a text editor, which you can simply edit to `pick` only the commits you want.